# circuit in Conway’s Game of Life

Tags: logic, cellular-automata

Let's assume that the bits in the Moore neighborhood are numbere as follows:

$$\begin{array}{lll}
a_4 & a_3 & a_2 & a_{11}\\
a_5  & {\large a_0}  & a_1 & a_{10} \\
a_6 & a_7 & a_8 & a_9
\end{array}$$

and let $x$, which belongs to the set of positive integers, denote time. For Conway’s Game of Life, how to draw a circuit that calculates
$а_0(x + 1)$ in terms of $а_0(x), \ldots , а_8(x)$.

Thanks much in advance!!!!

Comment: You might want to post this on stack overflow. Not that it isn't on topic here, you just might get a better response there.

Comment: what is $b_0$??

Comment: Sorry) That was typing error)))

Comment: What does "circuit" mean?

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121169/circuit-in-conways-game-of-life where I expect it to be closed, fast.

Comment: What are $a_9, a_{10}, a_{11}$ for?

Comment: @ChrisEagle - isn't a `circuit` a particular type of `graph` or `network`? - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1598203/157195

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a logic circuit to calculate the next state. I uses a lot of XOR and AND gates, a few OR gates and a couple of NOT gates. It basically sums the number of surrounding cells $S = a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8$ and then produces a $1$ if $S=3$ or $S+a0=3$.

[image: Calculating the value of a0(t+1) from a0..a8 using logic gates]

I haven't tested it, so there is probably a mistake somewhere.