# two node graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

There is only two node Node A and Node B in an undirected graph.

Is {A,B,A} a path, cycle or circuit?

My answer is {A,B,A} is a circuit,but not a cycle

[image]

Comment: Which definitions of path, cycle and circuit are you using? Graph theory is rife with alternative definitions for basic concepts.

Comment: I see you've edited your post to include what you think the answer is. However, I suggest that you also edit it to include the precise definitions of path, cycle and circuit that you're using in your book/course.

Comment: handshaking lemma, path and circuit

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to answer my question re definitions.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655589/what-is-difference-between-cycle-path-and-circuit-in-graph-theory

Answer (score 1):

If you subscribe to the definitions [here](http://www.edmath.org/MATtours/discrete/concepts/cwalk.html), it's a path and a cycle but not a circuit.