# What is the correct term for cycles more fundamental than Simple Cycles?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Consider the following undirected graph:

```
    a  
   / \  
 /     \  
b-------c  
 \     /  
  \   /  
    d
```

From the top-voted answer to [Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388696/1339950) I recently learned that the term Simple Cycle includes all three of the cycles in this graph:  abca, bcdb, and abdca.  (I originally thought Simple Cycles would only include abca and bdcb.)

Yet the Euler Equation would tell me that there are
E - N + 1 = 5 - 4 + 1 = 2 cycles

Clearly these 2 cycles would be abca and bcdb.

What is the correct term for just those cycles?

Comment: Also, considering this answer (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1221374/61558) and the comment under it, could there be ambiguity in this terminology?

Comment: Are you looking for the boundary cycles of the _faces_ in the particular drawing of the graph you're looking at? Those won't be the same if you consider a _different_ drawing of the _same_ graph.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for.  The only type of different drawing I can envision is one where d is moved so that edge bd crosses two other edges.  Is there some other drawing (transformation) that I am not anticipating?  And if so, what is the Euler Equation actually counting?

Comment: @Smylic: I think that's true for _polyhedral_ (i.e. 3-connected) graphs, but _planar_ graphs are a slightly larger class where the faces are not always intrinsically determined.

Comment: @Smylic, yes, I noticed that I could put d inside the abca triangle.  But there are still just two faces: abca and bcdb.  Is this the term I am looking for? Face?

Comment: @philologon: If you put d inside the triangle, the (inner) faces are now bcdb and abdca.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, this helps me understand it a little better.  I am also seeing how this means I need to ask a new question -- my higher-level problem has to do with cuts and possibly commodity flow.  We will be avoiding computing flow rates if we can -- we just need to know about whether a cut converts one graph into two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the cycles that form the boundaries of the *inner faces* of the graph -- in a particular planar drawing of it.

Note that this can depend on *which drawing* of the graph you're looking at. For example, consider this graph:

```
  B------C
 / \    / \
G---A  D---H
 \ /    \ /
  F------E
```

Here, if I understand you correctly, one of the cycles you want to consider is ABCDEF. However if instead we draw the same graph as

```
  B------C
 / \    / \
G---A  H---D
 \ /    \ /
  F------E
```

then ABCDEF suddenly doesn't border a face (not even the outer one).

The *number of faces* is still the same (due to the Euler formula), but they're different ones.

Comment: Is there a concept of faces with the shortest edge distance (by edge count)? In such a case as this, that would still identify abca and bcdb, omitting abdca as I was naively thinking it ought to be anyway

Comment: @philologon: Not really -- for this particular example, ABCDEF and ABCHEF have the same length, but both cannot be faces at the same time.

Comment: In my application (I think) it will not matter which Cycle wins the race to be counted as a face, but I will be favoring shorter circuits.