# Minimum number of edges in a cycle in Directed and Undirected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently reading about graph theory and came across something that confused me.

Say we have a walk between vertices $x$ and $y$. If vertex $x$ does not equal to vertex $y$ then it is called a path. However, if $x = y$ then it is called a cycle.

What confused me is that there are at least three distinct edge to form a cycle. I understand that it is the case for undirected graph, but why is it also the case for a directed graph. Can't we have $2$ edges to form a cycle?

For example, lets say we have a directed graph with vertices $x,y$ and edges $x\to y$ and $y \to x$. Doesn't this graph form a cycle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tack on to Fuseques' answer that highlights the distinction for simple graphs.

> Say we have a walk between vertices $x$ and $y$. If vertex $x$ does not equal to vertex $y$ then it is called a path. However, if $x = y$ then it is called a cycle.

Be a little bit careful with your definitions.

A *walk* between $2$ vertices $x$ and $y$, commonly referred to as an $xy$-walk, is a sequence of vertices (or vertices and edges, but naming the edges is not necessary) that we can traverse to get from $x$ to $y$. Note that in a walk, edges and vertices can repeat.

A *trail* is a walk that does not repeat an edge.

A *path* is a walk that does not repeat vertices (and thus does not repeat edges).

Now some may fuzz this definition a bit to say that that we can have a *closed* path in order to define cycles. You can see the differences in the way cycles are defined at [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)).

A closed walk, i.e. an $xx$-walk is not necessarily a cycle, but a cycle is a closed walk. (See Misha Lavrov's comment).

An example:
[image: An example graph.]

A walk (in this case closed) would be $1-2-3-4-5-2-3-4-5-2-1$.

A trail would be $1-2-3-4-5-2$.

A path would be $4-3-2-1-6-9-8$.

Comment: In an undirected graph, a closed walk only implies the existence of a cycle if it does not take the same edge twice. (There's probably a term for such closed walks, but I forget it.) Otherwise, for any edge $xy$, $x - y - x$ is a closed walk, whether or not cycles exist.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah, you are totally right. I have edited accordingly. Many thanks!

Comment: @MishaLavrov A closed walk with no repeated edges is traditionally called a **circuit**. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655589/what-is-difference-between-cycle-path-and-circuit-in-graph-theory

Answer (score 1):

> What confused me is that there are at least three distinct edge to
>   form a cycle. I understand that it is the case for undirected graph

It is not the case for undirected graphs, it is the case for **simple** undirected graphs (and also for simple directed graphs for that matter), where multiple edges between two vertices are not allowed, and neither do edges between vertices to themselves.

In a directed\undirected graph that is not simple, you can have a cycle formed with two edges between two vertices, and even a single edge cycle formed by an edge from a vertex to itself (also called a "loop").