# Clarification: Cycle vs Circuit in Undirected Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1574013709000483), and I need some help with clarifying what exactly is the difference between *cycle* and *circuit*:

> A cycle in an undirected graph is a subgraph in which every
> vertex has even degree. A cycle is a circuit if it is connected
> and every one of its vertices has degree two.

The subgraph of a graph $G = (V,E)$, by their definition, is $G' = (V',E')$ where $V' \subseteq V$ and $E' \subseteq E$. 
**Question 1**: Does *degree* in this statement mean the degree in $G$ or the subgraph $G'$? Neither really makes sense, for example with the following:
[image]

In the first example, (2)-(3)-(4) is clearly a cycle (at least as taught in any intro CS course). If we take it as a subgraph, then all of its vertices have even degrees in the subgraph, so it seems that the "even degree" definition applies to the subgraph $G'$. However, in the second example, (2)-(3)-(4)-(5) wouldn't be a cycle by this definition, since (2) and (4) have degree 3 in the subgraph marked in red, but this feels very weird to me. Similarly, if the "even degree" definition applies to the original $G$, then the first example wouldn't be a cycle since both (2) and (4) have degree 3.

**Question 2**: By this definition, $circuits \subset cycles$. Intuitively, is *circuit* the "simplest" *cycle* (only one "loop" in the subgraph $G'$)?

To further confuse myself, I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655589/what-is-difference-between-cycle-path-and-circuit-in-graph-theory),

> Circuit : Vertices may repeat. Edges cannot repeat (Closed) 
> Cycle : Vertices cannot repeat. Edges cannot repeat (Closed)

**Question 3**: Now, $cycles \supset circuits$?

Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.

Comment: Going by Figure 2 in the same paper, the degree is in the subgraph.

Comment: In your example the subgraph $\{23,24,34,25,45\}$ isn't a cycle but $\{23,34,25,45\}$ is.

Comment: For Q3, the definitions in that post are for various types of walks, not for graphs. In a cycle walk you can traverse each vertex exactly once, in a circuit walk you can traverse a vertex many times.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, could you elaborate a little further on the difference between a walk and a graph? My understanding is that a walk from that post is still a subgraph as defined in that paper.

Comment: A walk is a sequence $(e_n)$ of edges in a graph such that $e_n$ and $e_{n+1}$ have a common vertex. Take the triangle graph $\{e_1=12,e_2=23,e_3=13\}$. Then $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is a walk that is a circuit and a cycle, but $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_2,e_3)$ is a walk that is not a circuit or a cycle. $(e_1,e_1)$ is also a walk that is not a circuit or a cycle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)